# How to draw a simple Gantt chart in latex?

Tags: pgfgantt

I wanted to draw a simple Gantt chart like the following picture, but I saw that many instructions about Gantt charts on the Internet are much more complicated than I expected.   [image: the targeted Gantt chart]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `tikzpicture` (not really Gant diagram):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
G/.style = {draw, fill=gray!30, text width=2*#1mm, align=center,
            inner xsep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, 
            anchor=south west},
tck/.style = {font=\scriptsize, below}
                    ]
\foreach \n/\i [remember=\i as \j (initialy 0), 
                evaluate=\i as \k using \i-\j] in {P_4/3, P_1/9, P_3/16, P_2/24}
{
\node[G=\k]     at (\j/5,0) {$\n$};
    \node[tck]    at (\i/5,0) {\i};
\ifnum\j=0
    \node[tck]    at (0,0) {\j};
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for pointing out my misunderstandings; I think I misunderstood the Gantt chart.

Comment: @FitterJack, does answer solve your temporary problem? If not, look to `pgfgant` package.

Comment: yeah, it worked as intended.